# Why doesn't color of body background change on button click?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a button to change the HTML body's color between two colors.

This is the relevant JS I tried

```
document
  .getElementsByTagName("button")[0]
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
    if ((document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "white" )) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "blue";
    }

    if ((document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "blue")) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "white";
    }
  });
```

As you can see, I'm trying to make the background color toggle betweeen *white* and *blue* on button click, but nothing happens.

Could you help me undestanding what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: whats sems to be the problem?

Comment: What's the prob?

Comment: Can you explain your problem with a minimum set of details and code with which it can be reproduced? The code fragment you added is valid and should work. If it doesn't, what's the error?

Comment: use`==` to test  `if(variable == data)`

Comment: @yunnosch, not me. I'm not the OP, I'm just a lurker. I just noticed how the sample code was quite complete. Though the question could actually contain a better description of the actual behavior, the title could be corrected with an edit, and the same can be done making explicit the implicit question "I want to toggle the background color of the body. Why doesn't it toggle?".  The question was answerable, and in fact it received answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double equals instead of single equals. Single simply assigns the value to the left-hand side. Just add `==` to the if condition. Also add an `else if` condition to toggle between the colors on button click like this:

```
document
  .getElementsByTagName("button")[0]
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
    if ((document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background == "white" )) {

      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "blue";
    }
    else if ((document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background == "blue")) {

      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "white";
    }

 });
```

Also you have to give body a color, since by default body has transparent.

**Complete code:**

```js
document
    .getElementsByTagName("button")[0]
    .addEventListener("click", function() {
       if ((document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background == "white" )) { 

        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "blue";
       }
       else if ((document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background == "blue")) {

         document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "white";
       }

   });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background:white">


<button>Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```